# JavaScript function is only working the first time I call it?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering whether you guys could help me troubleshoot an issue I'm having. Hopefully identifying the problem won't require you look into the documentation of the graphics package I'm using, but if it does, here you go: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform.

I have the following block of code

```
window.setInterval(function()
{
    mycirc.transform("t1,1");
}, 500);
```

which of course should call the function `mycirc.transform("t1,1")` every half-second. That function is supposed to translate the x and y coordinates of `mycirc` each by 1 unit (look at Element.transform([tstr]) on http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform).

However, when I test my page, `mycirc` gets translated once and then the subsequent calls have no effect. I used `console.log(...)` to test and make sure:

```
window.setInterval(function()
{
    var bb = mycirc.getBBox();
    console.log("coords before transformation: " + bb.x + "," + bb.y);
    mycirc.transform("t1,1");
    var bb = mycirc.getBBox();
    console.log("coords after transformation: " + bb.x + "," + bb.y);

}, 500);
```

yields

```
coords before transformation: 120.98508107696858,106 jsfunctions.js:411
coords after transformation: 121.98508107696858,107 jsfunctions.js:414
coords before transformation: 121.98508107696858,107 jsfunctions.js:411
coords after transformation: 121.98508107696858,107 jsfunctions.js:411
```

etcetera.

Any idea why this might be?

(I tried to look through the source code for the graphics package, but it's unreadable because of no whitespace.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code

```
mycirc.transform("t1,1");
```

isn't relative to current state. It just transforms from original state to `t1,1` and then from `t1,1` to `t1,1` etc.

You should calculate transformation every time.

**EDIT**: So it would need a global variable, incremented every time like:

```
var xyPos = 1;
window.setInterval(function()
{
    mycirc.transform("t"+xyPos+","+xyPos);
    xyPos++;
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the usage section of the docs you linked, it shows how to prepend and append transformations. This implies to me that you code will just reset the transformation to the same thing every time. I have never used this graphics library, so I can't say for sure, but try something like the following and see if it works:

```
mycirc.transform("t1,1");
mycirc.transform("...t1,1");
mycirc.transform("...t1,1");
mycirc.transform("...t1,1");
```

I believe that will apply the same transform 4 times. Of course, you will then need to convert this logic into an interval for your use.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is expected behavior. Quoting the docs:

> Adds transformation to the element which is separate to other
>   attributes, i.e. translation doesn’t change x or y of the rectange.

Try:

```
var amount = 1;
window.setInterval(function()
{
    mycirc.transform("t" + [amount, amount].join(','));
    amount++;
}, 500);
```